# Weak sequential convergence-counterexample.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

My question has to do with an exercise in Royden's Real Analysis.

Let $E=\left \{ e_n+ne_m:m>n\in \mathbb N \right \}$ be a set of points in $l^2$ and show that although $0$ is in the weak-closure, there is no sequence in $E$ that converges weakly to $0$. Here is my attempt, with a comment/question at the end:

If $f\in (l^{2})^*=l^{2}$ is the sequence $(x_k)$ then $f(e_n+ne_m)=x_n+nx_m.$ For $\epsilon>0,$ choose $n$ large enough so that $|x_n|\le \frac{\epsilon }{2}$ and fix it. Now choose $m>n$ large enough so that $|nx_m|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}.$ This shows That $0\in \overline E^{w}.$

Now, let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $E,$ and by passing to a subsequence if necessary, assume that the first occurrence of $ne_m$ in each succesive term in the sequence is strictly to the right of that in the previous one.

We have $y_1=e_{k_1}+k_1e_{m_1}; m_1>k_1$ for some $k_1\in \mathbb N$. Let $x^1$ be the $\textit {finite}$ sequence $\underbrace{(0,0\cdots,0, \frac{1}{k_1})}_{{m_1}}.$  In general, we have $y_i=e_{k_i}+k_ie_{m_i},$ and so can define inductively the sequence $x^i$ by cancatenation. For example, $x^2$ is the finite sequence $\underbrace{(0,0\cdots,0, \frac{1}{k_1},}_{{m_1}}\underbrace{0,0\cdots,0, \frac{1}{k_2})}_{{m_2-m_1}}).$

This process gives us an $f\in (l^2)^*$ with the property that $f(y_n)\ge 1$ so $(y_n)$ does not converge weakly to $0.$

But since the exercise in Royden appears before the study of Hilbert spaces, or the duality theorems, I guess there should be another (simpler?) way of showing this, from first principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weakly convergent sequence is bounded. So if $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a weakly convergent sequence in $E$, say $x_k = e_{n_k} + n_k e_{m_k}$, then $(n_k)$ is a bounded sequence of natural numbers, hence contains only finitely many distinct terms. Thus at least one $n_k$ occurs infinitely often, call it $\nu$. Then

$$\langle x_k, e_{\nu}\rangle = 1$$

for infinitely many $k$, whence the weak limit is not $0$.